# getElementsByClassName error within a div

Tags: javascript, html, selector, getelementsbyclassname

I have a page with multiple div's containing html5 video players. Basically something like this

```
<div class="panel">
  <video class="player"><source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <video class="player"><source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" /></video>
</div>
...
```

Now I want to iterate through all elements with the class "panel" and pause all videoplayers. So I'm trying this in JavaScript:

```
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
  var video = panels[i].getElementsByClassName("player");
  video.pause();
}
```

What I get is this error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: panels[i].getElementByClassName is not a function`

Is there anybody who can help me fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: seems weird you do not just reference player directly since it would be faster.

Comment: You have typos in your code, can you post the actual code

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName`, only `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: Sorry for the typos - I fixed them!

Comment: epascarello - You're right, this one works fine too:
panels[i].getElementsByClassName("player")[0].pause();
Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a mispelling.  It refers to:

```
document.getElemtsByClassName(...)
```

which should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(...)
```

Assuming that is just a typo in your question (since you don't report the error that would cause), then:

---

**This line of code gets an HTMLCollection, not an individual DOM element:**

```
var video = panels[i].getElementsByClassName("player");
```

So, you can't do:

```
 video.pause();
```

because `video` in that above line of code is an HTMLCollection, not a DOM element and an HTMLCollection doesn't have a `.pause()` method.  To get a DOM element from the HTMLCollection, you have to reach into it with an property index to get an individual DOM element:

```
 video[0].pause();
```

Or, you can iterate the whole HTMLCollection to operate on all the DOM elements in the HTML collection.  This would be getting the first player object in each div (see the `[0]`):

```
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
  var video = panels[i].getElementsByClassName("player")[0];
  video.pause();
}
```

Or, if you wanted all player objects using this technique, you would need to use two `for` loops:

```
var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
  var videos = panels[i].getElementsByClassName("player");
  for (var j = 0; j < videos.length; j++) {
      videos[j].pause();
  }
}
```

You also may just want to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and do this all in one query and one iteration:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll(".panel .player");
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].pause();
}
```

Also, given your HTML, it's not entirely clear why you first query `.panel` elements.  If you have no other `.player` objects that you're trying to avoid, you can just get the player objects directly in a simpler query:

```
var videos = document.querySelectorAll(".player");
for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].pause();
}
```

---

And, though you didn't ask about using jQuery, it's often useful for DOM queries, iterations and manipulations:

```
$(".panel .player").each(function() {
    this.pause();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick!
I also want to set attributes on the panels - so your second suggestion doesn't work for me but is a great hint for other users I guess!